# How to redirect folder without affecting its files in apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have the following rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /products http://example.com/products.html
```

Which works fine, however it's affecting the URLs of the files inside the folder so:

```
http://example.com/products/item.html
```

Gets redirected to:

```
http://example.com/products.html/item.html
```

Is there any way that I can only target the parent folder with my redirect and not the files inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can only target the parent folder with my redirect and not the files inside it?

Yes use `RedirectMatch` for precise targeting using a **regex**:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/?$ http://example.com/products.html
```

Regex `^/products/?$` will match `/product` or `/product/` but NOT `/product/file`.

Comment: Thanks I was toying around with RedirectMatch but I couldn't get the regex right